# Nginx в ubuntu игнорирует все кастомные конфиги

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, config

по неизвестной мне причине, nginx на ubuntu 16.04-x86_64  не хочет принимать созданные мной конфиги не под каким предлогам, уперся в то что статика не раздается, бился вначале над правильностью написания но тест говорил что все верно(nginx перезапускал после каждого сохранения), 1ый раз решил удалить симлинк на дефолтный конфиг, в итоге серевер лег и даже после востановления симлинка не захотел фурычить, и после переустановки(полной) nginx тоже, пришлось сносить систему и ставить по новой.

Второй раз столкнулся с такой же проблемой доходил до настройки статики и т.к там нужно настраивать конфиг опят затык получилось только затерв старый дефолтный конфиг и вписал туда свой, как ни странно все заработало. Но все мне надо что бы работали конфиги созданные рядом

Прошу помощи, с чем это может быть связано и как это побороть!

Comment: "конфиги" чего, сервера или хостов? где они размещены, ваши "конфиги" в `sites-*`?  Как они выглядят, для примера?

Comment: Конфиг для сервера nginx, вроде понятно расписал. Дефолтный конфиг он воспринимает, а созданные мной и помещенные в /etc/nginx/sites-enabled  симлинки не воспринимает абсолютно.
Сам конфиг лежит в папке проекта /var/www/mysite/

Comment: Для начала посмотреть в error log

Comment: Пустой постоянно, только когда default перезаписал, начались вываливаться ошибки о невозможности получить доступ к файлам джанги, но это к делу не относится

Comment: Я всё-таки подозреваю, что nginx просто не может прочитать файлы из `/var/www/mysite`

Comment: Я пробовал и из /etc/nginx/sites-available делать силинк, что странно, мне ТП хостинга ставила ssl и положив файл напрямую в /etc/nginx/sites-enabled  без симлинка, у них все заработало